# Python most accurate method to measure time (ms)

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I need to meassure the time certain parts of my code take. While executing my code on a powerfull server, I get 10 diffrent results

I tried comparing time measured with `time.time()`, `time.perf_counter()`, `time.perf_counter_ns()`, `time.process_time()` and `time.process_time_ns()`.

```py
import time

for _ in range(10):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    i = 0
    while i < 100000:
        i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)
```

I'm expecting when executing the same code 10 times, to be the same (the results to have a resolution of at least 1ms) ex. 1.041XX and not 1.030sec - 1.046sec.

```
When executing my code on a 16 cpu, 32gb memory server I'm receiving this result:

1.045549364
1.030857833
1.0466020120000001
1.0309665050000003
1.0464690349999994
1.046397238
1.0309525370000001
1.0312070380000007
1.0307592159999999
1.046095523

Im expacting the result to be: 

1.041549364
1.041857833
1.0416020120000001
1.0419665050000003
1.0414690349999994
1.041397238
1.0419525370000001
1.0412070380000007
1.0417592159999999
1.041095523
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner im not looking for average time, im just expacting the same time, when i execute the same part of code to take the same the as the last iteration. I dont undersand why it takes sometimes more and sometimes less time.

Comment: see my answer and the documentation of sleep()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. If you want to measure code average time consumption use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module. It executes your code multiple times and averages over the times.

The reason your code has different runtimes lies in your code:

```
time.sleep(1)  # ensures (3.5+) _at least_ 1000ms are waited, won't be less, might be more
```

You are calling it in a tight loop,resulting in accumulated differences:

Quote from [time.sleep(..) documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time **may be less** than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension **time may be longer than requested** by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: The function now **sleeps at least sec**s even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler raises an exception (see PEP 475 for the rationale).

**Emphasis** mine.

Comment: yes, time.sleep must be the problem, so I will need to find a more accurate way to pause my code, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Perfoming a code do not take the same time at each loop iteration because of the scheduling of the system (system puts on hold your process to perform another process then back to it...).

Comment: To understand that, see you process manager on your PC (`top` commmand if you are on Unix) and you will see that you have lot of process launched but less available cores.